# Django - Anyway to call a view function from a button on a template?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

I have seen a couple of this same question posted but I am still not understanding how to do this. I have template that displays hyperlinks leading to the actual record to be updated. I want to put a button on the template that just displays the list to be able to create records in a table by looping over each of the records in this "temp" table. The behavior is meant to mimic a Cart on a eCommerce site. That is why I am storing the records in this temp table because when they "Check-out" they will be considered 1 order with multiple lines.

Writing the logic in the view isnt the issue, its calling this function when the button is pressed that I am not understanding. Thank you!

### EDIT:

I wrote some psuedocode for what behavior i want to happen when the submit button is clicked

```
def process_basket(request):
    basket = table1
    dbtable = table2

    for each record in basket:
        create new record in dbtable
        delete record in basket after 

    refresh page to show empty list
```

### Updated:

basket.html

```
{% load static %}

{% if user_list %}
    <table>
    {% for created_req in user_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'requisition:basket_item' created_req.id %}">{{ created_req }}</a>     
            </td>
        </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <form action="{% url 'requisition:process_basket' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="button" value="Submit Req">
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>No requisitions in basket</p>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
path('basket/', views.basket_list, name='basket'),
path('basket/<int:id>/', views.update_basket_item, name='basket_item'),
path('basket/process/', views.process_basket, name='process_basket')
```

views.py

```
def process_basket(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = CurrentUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
        basket_list = ReqBasket.objects.filter(user=user)
        # Make decision as to set the status depending on what flag is ticked
        #   Assitance, Submitted 


        cur_status = RequisitionStatus.objects.get(status='Created')
        header = Requisition.objects.create(username=user, status=cur_status)
        for line in len(basket_list):
            req_line = RequisitionLine.objects.create(
                                        parent_req = header,
                                        sequence = line,
                                        description = basket_list.description,
                                        extra_information=basket_list.extra_information,
                                        quantity = basket_list.quantity,
                                        price = basket_list.price,
                                        req_delivery_date = basket_list.req_delivery_date)
        return redirect(reverse('requisition:submitted_reqs'))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('requisition:basket'))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your models?

Comment: Through an AJAX call.

Comment: @sachin I havent tried anything yet, I just want to call a function to run when the button is pressed. I dont want to do a url call.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I havent done any work with AJAX calls can you preform a little more information if you dont mind?

Comment: @K.Pardo If you want to store the data in the database, you need to make an additional request to the server.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I would expect to do that in the function i am calling. I need this button to trigger the function I have written.

Comment: Which function are you talking about? Please post that.

Comment: @SachinKukreja posted psuedocode

Comment: To trigger this function, you need to have an additional url to which you will make a request.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Ah I see now what you're saying, I am implementing it now thank you so much! It ended up being simpler then I was making it out to be.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I can't get the button to trigger the url request. If you dont mind taking a look at the code I will be updating the post.

Comment: button's `type` attribute should `submit`, not `button`.

Comment: @SachinKukreja I am getting a Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted now when i try to call the function with a post call. I added the csrf token in my template under the form tag

Answer (score 0):

From what you stated above (mimicking a shopping cart) I think your solution is more of a front-end one. Use Javascript and the browser's Sessions or Localstorage API. When it's time for checkout, you can now send it over to the server and that's when Django comes into place.